# git push update issue

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project with multiple developers on different branches, which exists on let's say: "...github.com/owner/project".

There is the usual "master", "me", and several "other" branches.

I would like to create a new github repo and push my local copy there. However, when I create a new github repo, add remote, and push, a much older version gets pushed instead of the latest local copy.

I searched around and saw answers about "detached heads" and similar terms that I'm not too familiar with. I'm not an expert on git either, so I guess the best thing I can do is to post the steps I followed and the configuration options.

```
Create new github repo called "project_copy" from github account ...

cd to local repo ...

git remote add project_copy ...github.com/me/project_copy.git

git config --list (a part is shown below):

remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=...github.com/owner/project
remote.project_copy.url=...github.com/me/project_copy.git
remote.project_copy.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/project_copy/*

git push project_copy master
```

This is the output I get:

```
To ...github.com/me/project_copy.git
* [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from project_copy.
```

Normally I would use the following to push changes to my branch:

```
git push origin me
```

Comment: It looks like you pushed `master` to `project_copy`, but you didn't push `me`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, that solved it. This was due to my misunderstanding of some git basics. If you want to, you can post your comment in the form of an answer so I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running

```
git push project_copy master
```

you push your `master` branch to the `project_copy` remote. This can be seen in the output:

```
* [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from project_copy.
```

But it sounds like your recent work is in a different branch called `me`. If you want to share your work in `me` you've got a few options, two of which are

- to merge `me` into `master` locally and `git push project_copy master` again, or
- to push the `me` branch to `project_copy` using `git push project_copy me`.

The first option is likely the right choice if you're done working on `me` and want to integrate it into your `master` branch. The second is likely right if you want to keep `me` separate from `master`.

Note that you can also push `me` to a remote branch with a different name. For instance, if `me` makes sense to you, but your team would prefer to see a branch called `feature/add-something`, you can run `git push project_copy me:feature/add-something`.

See [the documentation for `git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) for more details. The [Refspec section in Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) is also worth reading.